# JRuby - stopping script execution

Tags: jruby

Is there any way to stop a script after it has executed a particular amount of time?

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather vaguely defined question. Here are a few ideas that come to mind:

1. Use a shell as the control process. Start the JRuby script, send it into the background, sleep for a fixed amount of time, then kill `$!`.
2. At the beginning of your JRuby script, create a thread that sleeps for a fixed amount of time, and then kill the entire script.
3. If you're using an embedded JRuby, you can use Java's threads to do exactly what you want.

Comment: _If you're using an embedded JRuby, you can use Java's threads to do exactly what you want._ Yes, I'm using it inside jvm. but how do i stop it?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question. My current approach looks like this (and does not work as expected...):

```
// jruby-complete-1.6.0.RC2.jar
import org.jruby.Ruby;

class JRubyStop {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final Ruby jruby = Ruby.newInstance();
        Thread jrubyThread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                String scriptlet = "for i in 0..100; puts i; sleep(1); end";
                jruby.evalScriptlet(scriptlet);
            }
        };
        jrubyThread.start();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("interrupt!");
        jrubyThread.interrupt();
        System.out.println("interrupted?!");
    }
}
```

After the output of "interrupted?!" the thread still runs until the scriptlet ends.

**Edit:** Converted Groovy example into a Java SSCCE (http://sscce.org/).

Comment: _After the output of "interrupted?!" the thread still runs until the scriptlet ends._ If your's is a simple application, you can try using Thread.stop() instead of Thread.interrupt()

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I accually was reluctant to use Thread.stop() since it is deprecated. I've to test this a bit more, because I have to call several Java methods with Ruby.

Comment: I also found http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-4135 where some JRuby guys talk about issues with interrupting threads.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the link. I'll let you know if this works. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

super late answer but this is what I use:

```
require 'timeout'
status = Timeout::timeout(5) 

{
  # Something that should be interrupted if it takes more than 5 seconds...
}
```